# Pregmatch Validation for allowing only one special character

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

I need a pregmatch for checking 10 character string which allows only numbers and  letters of maximum length 10 followed by a hyphen (-), so the length should be maximum 11.

That means if users enter 10 numbers or letters then the maximum length of string should be 10 and if enters one hyphen then the length of the string should be 11.

`^(?=.{0,10}$).*` is the pattern that I am using currently. It is allowing for 10 characters only but accepting any special character.

Comment: Can you show your current regex please. The valid string should always have 10  but if special 11 characters. Or could it be of variable length valid: 1-10 but if special: 11?

Comment: ^(?=.{0,10}$).* is the pregmatch i am using currently.It is allowing for 10 digits only but accepting any special character.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow at most one hyphen anywhere in the string but disallow 11 alphanumeric, try

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,11}$)(?![a-zA-Z0-9]{11})[^-]*-?[^-]*$
```

- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,11}$)` checks if only consists of alphanumeric characters + hyphen
- `(?![a-zA-Z0-9]{11})` negative lookahead to disallow 11 without hyphen
- `[^-]*-?[^-]*$` one optional hyphen anywhere in the string

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vM3iH8/3)

Comment: can we change it to allow only hyphen(-) as special character please?

Comment: @user1755949 Sure, just replace `[^[:alnum:]]` with `-` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/oI5uA4/1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i am getting "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group" after using this. i am using the pregmatch on a textbox and validating in javascript.But in javascript i am getting this error on validate.

Comment: @user1755949 Try `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,11}$)(?![a-zA-Z0-9]{11})[^-]*-?[^-]*$` JS doesn't support posix classes or conditionals. This would allow a hyphen in strings from 1-11 but disallows 11 alphas only.

Comment: @user1755949 Please award this answer the green tick so that future SO readers will know that this question is successfully answered.